# Adding Wallet using web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add

Tags: web3js, wallets, contract-deployment, infura

On web3 0.20.1, I am using Infura to deploy a contract to Rinkeby. This probably requires me to add a wallet to `web3.accounts` to provide the gas needed.

When I ran the following nodejs code,

```
Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/nyxynyx-api-key"))
var privateKey = 'nyxynyx-private-key'
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("0x" + privateKey);

var contractCode = '60606-contract-code-here';
var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"givenNumber","type":"uint8"}],"name":"setNumber","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"givenNumber","type":"uint8"}],"name":"guessNumber","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"SetNumber","type":"event"}];
GuessNumber = web3.eth.contract(abi)
var contractInstance = GuessNumber.new({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 200000, data: '0x' + contractCode});
```

the following error is encountered:

```
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("0x" + privateKey);
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Is this because `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add` is a web3 v1.0 function? If it is, what is the equivalent code needed in v0.20.1?

Answer (score 2):

First create a wallet object.
first parameter is number of accounts which you want and the second parameter is 32 byte random array as an entropy

```
var wallet = w3.eth.accounts.wallet.create(0, utils.entropy())
```

then add new account to your created wallet with

```
var newAccount = w3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(textPrivateKey.text)
wallet.add(newAccount)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution to your problem**

We can also use this method to add wallet in our eth.wallets

*Points to be look at :-*

1. We are taking values of interface and bytecode from another file which is having our contract code compiled in it.
2. hdwalletprovider input your 12 word mnemonic and rinkeby address

`const hdwalletprovider=require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3=require('web3');
const {interface,bytecode}=require('./compile');

```
const provider=new hdwalletprovider(
    'hello blue cat eng cook name version brave entire sail trumpet scrub', // 12 word mnemonic
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/5d5eaf76b6a84578a245e058b870a8aa' );

const web3=new Web3(provider);

const deploy=async() => {
    const accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts[0]);

   const result=await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
   .deploy({data : bytecode})
   .send({gas: '10000000', from: accounts[0] });

   console.log(result.options.address);
};

deploy();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Web3 v1.0 is far superior in my experience, so I recommend switching over when convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v1.0, then try using
`web3.eth.accounts.create(\*Passcode here*\);` to create new wallets